# Redownloaded custom built tensorflow wheel wont install

Tags: tensorflow, pip, bazel

I've built Tensorflow with custom SIMD extensions and created a wheel for it. If I simply do `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.wh` on the box that I built it on, that works. However if I upload the `whl` file to cloud storage, and do `pip install https://storage.cloud.google.com/path/to/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` I get this error:

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.0.0 from https://storage.cloud.google.com/path/to/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading https://storage.cloud.google.com/path/to/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Do I need to configure my build differently somehow?

Comment: Can you try downloading the same URL (e.g. using `wget` or `curl`) and then `pip install`-ing the downloaded file?

Comment: Identical result, "File is not a zip file"

Comment: Does the `md5sum` of the file you downloaded match the file you uploaded?

Comment: No.... talk about not expecting the obvious, thanks!

Comment: It probably gave you HTML page asking to login instead of the actual wheel

Comment: Yep, I needed the base url to be `storage.googleapis.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(capturing the solution as an answer)

The URL used for the download is not correct. The base url needed to be `storage.googleapis.com`

Comment: nice digging, looks like I've  been using incorrect links all along